# For loop reverse order JAGS

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, jags

I am trying to figure out how to avoid to enter this for loop without using an `if` statement (not present in JAGS).

In other words, I need this loop not to run in reverse order, i.e. when `Je[i] - 1` is less than 2.

```
for (j in 2:(Je[i]-1)){
    Z[i,j] ~ dnegbin(p[i,j],r[eta[i,j]])
    logit(p[i,j]) <- B1[eta[i,j]] + B2*sum(Z[i,1:j-1])
}
```

When `Je[i] - 1 == 1`, the loop still runs but in reverse order, so `j` is first equal to 2 and in the second iteration `j` is equal to 1.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use an `if` statement for conditional execution of your for loop?

Comment: There is no if statement in JAGS software

Comment: I'm guessing the index `i` is from a for loop like `for(i in indexSet)`.  Perhaps you could write that `for` statement like this: `for(i in indexSet[Je[indexSet] - 1 >= 2])`